# Is there a way to parse a file with Opencsv containing EoF line?

Tags: java, opencsv

I have a semicolon delimited file which contains line `EoF` to indicate the end of file.

```
entries = new CsvToBeanBuilder(new FileReader(pathToFile))
        .withSeparator(';')
        .withType(Bean.class)
        .build().parse();
```

Sample input file:

```
H1;H2;H3
a;b;c
d;e;f
g;h;i
EoF
```

Opencsv can't understand `EoF` and throws `CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException: Number of data fields does not match number of headers.
```

Any idea how to make opencsv ignore `EoF`?

Comment: You could implement a filter to only include valid rows, [Filter doc](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/CsvToBeanFilter.html)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks, that is exactly what I needed